# How to publish ASMX-like help page for WCF BasicHttpBinding web service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wcf-binding

I have created a WCF web service with BasicHttpBinding. When I browse the .svc file, I get a link to WSDL definition and the *"You have created a service. To test this service, you will need to create a client..."*:

[image: WCF help page]

ASMX help page displays more verbose info about supported operations:

[image: ASMX help page]

Is there a way to display information about individual WCF service operations automatically as for ASMX services?

Answer (score 0):

```
<endpointBehaviors>
   <behavior name="MyCostumBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
   </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
<!-- ... -->
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="MyCostumBehavior"....
```

This configuration works for both SOAP and Rest WCF

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think it's possible to reference endpoint behaviour directly from the service tag. I got _"There is no service behavior named 'MyCostumBehavior'."_ when trying to use your example.

Comment: How is this answering the question?